# is there any way element overflow its parent

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, overflow

i want to overflow an element its parent context in css(bootstrap). is there any way ?

in my case code is below. I want the description fields to cover the whole row. but its in col-md-4 therefore not cover. Is there a way to do what i want. My English is bad, I'm sorry.

Edit: 
[the design i want to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuFlV.png)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
               <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                     item 1
                  </a>
               </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="panel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
               <div class="panel-body">
                  Description 1
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
               <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                     item 2
                  </a>
               </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="panel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
               <div class="panel-body">
                 description 2
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>

      
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to separate description (panel content) and put it below the tabs (headings)

And after all I think in this case you need Bootstrap's [accordion approach](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example)

Try this out:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true"
            aria-controls="collapseOne">
            item 1
          </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
            item 2
          </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="panel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
  <div class="panel-body">
    Description 1
  </div>
</div>
<div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="panel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
  <div class="panel-body">
    description 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. but did not provide a solution for my situation. i edit my question with a design screenshot. there are lots of col-md-4 class. i will search accordion approach.

Comment: I think I got what you need here - full width container that has to breakout from its parents width limits. Here's the good article to achieve that: https://css-tricks.com/full-width-containers-limited-width-parents/